# EF Core - LINQ - Assign property to IQueryable<T>

Tags: entity-framework, linq, iqueryable

I have some Entities I want to query by using LINQ:

```
public class Link: Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public Guid RelationId { get; private set; }
    public Guid ConstructionId { get; private set; }

    public virtual Relation Relation { get; private set; }
    public virtual Construction Construction { get; private set; }

    private Link()
    {
    }
}

public class Relation: Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public string Number { get; private set; }
    public Guid PersonId { get; private set; }
    public Guid RelationTypeId { get; private set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; private set; }
    public virtual RelationType RelationType { get; private set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int ContextKey { get; set; }

    private Relation()
    {
    }
}
```

I have a query that returns the relations by giving the construction id and using the Link entity. The query is as follows and it works as expected:

```
public IQueryable<Relation> GetRelationsByConstructionId(Guid constructionId)
{
    var links base.Get(x => x.Construction.ConstructionId == constructionId);

    var relations = links.Include(x => x.Relation)
                         .Select(x => x.Relation)
                         .Include(x => x.Person)
                         .Include(x => x.RelationType);

    return relations;
}
```

In Relation I have a NotMapped element ContextKey and I want to set this ContextKey in the query call (e.g. I want to set it to 30). Basically I want to do something like this to extend the query I use:

```
public IQueryable<Relation> GetRelationsByConstructionId(Guid constructionId)
{
    var links base.Get(x => x.Construction.ConstructionId == constructionId);

    var relations = links.Include(x => x.Relation)
                         .Select(x => x.Relation)
                         .Include(x => x.Person)
                         .Include(x => x.RelationType);

    var updatedRelations = relations.ForEachAsync(x => x.ContextKey = 30);

    return updatedRelations;
}
```

Ofcourse this does not work, because after the **ForEachAsync** the type of **updatedRelations** is *Task* and the return type that is expected has to be *IQueryable    < Relation    >*.

How can I make my query work and get the output I want in the correct *IQueryable    < Relation    >* type?

Comment: The direct fix is to add `async` and `await` at the appropriate locations, but if the only reason to go async is to use `ForEachAsync` that's overkill. There are more things wrong or doubtful in your code: 1) `var links base.Get...` doesn't even compile. 2) The first `Include` is redundant, and 3) (most important) this query doesn't necessarily return distinct relations because multiple constructions may have the same relation. If you want relations, query relations directly using a predicate that traverses to `constructionId`. (`Relation` needs a `Links` navigation property for that).

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the reasons I'm against unmapped properties - they doesn't fit in LINQ to Entities queries.

You can use the following LINQ to Objects trick:

```
var updatedRelations = relations
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => { x.ContextKey = 30; return x; })
    .AsQueryable();
```

but note that this isn't a real EF Core queryable, so further operations like filtering, ordering, paging etc. on it will be performed in memory on the materialized result of the query before `AsEnumerable()`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself by updating the query as follows:

```
public IQueryable<Relation> GetRelationsByConstructionId(Guid constructionId)
{
    var links base.Get(x => x.Construction.ConstructionId == constructionId);

    var relations = links.Include(x => x.Relation)
                     .Select(x => x.Relation)
                     .Include(x => x.Person)
                     .Include(x => x.RelationType);

    relations.ToList().ForEach(x => x.ContextKey = 30);

    return relations;
}
```

Comment: But this is even worse. The relations query (and related) will be executed twice - one with `ToList` and one from the external caller.